# Unreliable GPS readings using Phonegap on Nexus 5

Tags: android, cordova, gps

I am using `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` to grab the current position of a user.  The following options are passed: `{ maximumAge: 1000, timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: true }`.  However, two issues are occurring:

The timeout of 15 seconds is totally ignored. It seems to update as and when it wants to.  Sometimes it is after 10 seconds, other times it is over a minute.

The second issue is that often no GPS coordinates will be retrieved at all, and the method will return a timeout.  Once this happens once it will happen every 15 seconds indefinitely.

None of this makes much sense to me, so any insight would be great.

I am using:

- Nexus 5
- Phonegap version 3.3.0-0.18.0

The device has location services on, and the location it gives out initially is accurate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A workaround could be to call an Android Java class with JavascriptInterface

Comment: Sounds like quite a bit of hassle for something so basic.  Do you think it's device-specific or a widespread problem with Phonegap?

Comment: I would bet its a plugin issue due to kitkat. If you get the coordinates well via javascript, then it confirms its a cordova plugin issue. Also, check that you gave authorizations to use gps to apps as a user, with highest accuracy.